# "Splitting" string in assembly language

Tags: assembly, explode, split

I have new problem. I'm working with strings in assembly language and I want to ask: Is there any function in assembly language for "splitting" strings like Split in JavaScript, .NET and explode in PHP?

Comment: Do you want someone to write a function for you? Why don't you try first? There's no opcode to split strings if that's what you're thinking

Comment: No I don't write it. My problem is that I don't know how to code it and here I'm asking how to code it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure assembly? No. There is no such thing as a string on a cpu, just bytes. You'll have to either use a library like the c library, link it and use the usual c functions, or code it yourself in assembly.

Comment: And can I make it like that i will go character by character and I will compare it with delimiter? than if character will be delimiter, next characters (without another delimiters) will be written to another db?

Comment: I think you really need to think on a lower level than you are currently. What db? Assembly is moving bytes and adresses around, not characters or a even bigger, a database. The general concept is okay though. The function gets a pointer to an input array plus a single byte used as the delimiter and returns (by putting it into eax) a pointer to an output array.

Comment: sorry, instruction. String db "splitted string here".

Comment: Assembly (atleast x86) has a concept of strings, as there are specific string manip opcodes, like stos & movs (which got abused as generic memory op), scas, lods etc (http://www.etfos.hr/~jbognar/pozadine/temp/asembly%20tutorial/x86asm/asml1013.html), you are right about there being no splitting op though